# Top K subset sum without sorting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, subset

Given an array of size N, print all subsets of size K `(0<K<=N)` in the increasing order of the sum of elements

```
Array:
  [6,8,3,9], N=4, K=3
Sorted Subsets:
  [3, 6, 8] (sum=17)
  [3, 6, 9] (sum=18)
  [3, 8, 9] (sum=20)
  [6, 8, 9] (sum=23)
```

I don't need the entire sorted list but rather the top T entries (T being small). Listing out all subsets(nCk) and sorting them will be very expensive for large N. Is there a way to get the top T subsets without actually enumerating all the subsets? I was thinking on the lines of picking the smallest K elements, which is the smallest subset and then finding a way to obtain the next smallest subset by relacing one or more elements, but there are again too many choices for replacement.

Comment: Just a thought. If `K` is 3, and you take the smallest 4 elements of the input array, you'll get the four smallest subsets by choosing 3 of those 4. Take 5 elements, and you can form the smallest 5C3 subsets.

Comment: @user3386109 That won't work for example with `[3, 6, 7, 8, 9]` - your algorithm would generate `6, 7, 8` before `3, 6, 9`.

Comment: I'm not sure which step I missed. The point I'm making is that for some inputs, there can be a subset which includes the last element of the array, which is smaller than any subset not including the first element of the array, so any algorithm based on yielding subsets from iteratively-growing prefixes of the array is not going to work. Your statement that *"take the smallest 4 elements of the input array, you'll get the four smallest subsets by choosing 3 of those 4"* is false.

Comment: *"The point I'm making is that for some inputs, there can be a subset which includes the last element of the array"* I assume by that you mean that for some inputs, there can be a subset that includes the ***largest*** element of the array. Is that correct? @kaya3

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming the array is sorted.

Comment: @kaya3 Ok, so my original thought was that in the general case, the largest element of the array is not going to be needed. For example, if `k=3` and `T=10` and `N=100`, you don't need the 100th element of the array. And the thing to think about is, "how many elements of the array do you need?"

Comment: @user3386109, that is a nice observation. However, in the general case this doesn't help much. It would be nice to build a generator that would produce these in order by sum. In the general case we will definitely need the `Nth` element rather quickly.

Comment: @JosephWood The question *is* rather vague with regards to the input constraints. The two hints it gives are **(T being small)** and "**expensive for large N**". So I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly), that T is much smaller than N, and therefore the `Nth` element is not needed.

Comment: @user3386109 I see what you mean now. You are correct - you don't need any more than K + T - 1 elements from the list. That said, since the large number of combinations is like (N choose K) rather than just N, "large N" could be interpreted as "large (N choose K)".

Comment: @kaya3 That's true. Which is why I typically don't bother answering questions like this. Without knowing the input constraints, it's not clear what parts of the algorithm are critical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would solve this problem like this:

1. Sort the array, and let `s` be the sum of the first `k` elements.
2. Generate all subsets of sum equal to `s` using a [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch-and-bound).
3. Find the smallest `s2 > s` such that there is a subset whose sum equals `s2`, using a [branch-and-bound algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch-and-bound).
4. If there is such an `s2`, set `s = s2` and go to step 2. Otherwise, stop.

Here's an implementation in Python: it lazily generates every subset in order of sum, so you can just take the first T subsets that it yields.

```py
def subsets_in_sum_order(lst, k):
    """
    Returns a generator yielding the k-element subsets
    of lst, in increasing order of their sum.
    """
    lst = sorted(lst)
    s = sum(lst[:k])
    max_s = sum(lst[-k:])
    while s is not None:
        yield from subsets_of_sum(lst, k, s)
        s = smallest_sum_in_range(lst, k, s+1, max_s)

def subsets_of_sum(lst, k, s, t=(), i=0):
    """
    Returns a generator yielding tuples t + tt, where tt
    is a k-element subset of lst[i:] whose sum is s. The
    subsets are yielded in lexicographic order. The list
    lst must be sorted.
    """
    if k < 0:
        raise ValueError()
    elif k == 0:
        if s == 0:
            yield t
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(lst) - k + 1):
            if sum(lst[j:j+k]) > s: break
            v = lst[j]
            s2 = s - v
            t2 = t + (v,)
            yield from subsets_of_sum(lst, k-1, s2, t2, j+1)

def smallest_sum_in_range(lst, k, min_s, max_s, i=0):
    """
    Returns the smallest s such that min_s <= s <= max_s,
    and there is a k-element subset of lst[i:] with sum s.
    The list lst must be sorted.
    Returns None if there is no such s.
    """
    result = None
    if k < 0:
        raise ValueError()
    elif k == 0:
        if min_s <= 0:
            result = 0
    elif min_s <= max_s and sum(lst[-k:]) >= min_s:
        for j in range(i, len(lst) - k + 1):
            v = lst[j]
            if k * v > max_s: break
            s = smallest_sum_in_range(lst, k-1, min_s-v, max_s-v, j+1)
            if s is not None:
                s += v
                result = s
                max_s = s - 1
    return result
```

Example:

```py
>>> subsets = subsets_in_sum_order([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
>>> for subset in subsets:
...     print(subset, sum(subset))
... 
(1, 2, 3) 6
(1, 2, 4) 7
(1, 2, 5) 8
(1, 3, 4) 8
(1, 3, 5) 9
(2, 3, 4) 9
(1, 4, 5) 10
(2, 3, 5) 10
(2, 4, 5) 11
(3, 4, 5) 12
```

@user3386109 made the observation that if the list length is much larger than the number of subsets you want to generate, then we don't actually need the whole list, because the larger elements from the list can't occur in the first T subsets. The first T subsets must only use the first T + k - 1 elements from the list, so we can improve the efficiency a bit by using [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```py
import heapq
from itertools import islice

def smallest_subsets(lst, k, num_subsets):
    lst = heapq.nsmallest(num_subsets + k - 1, lst)
    subsets = subsets_in_sum_order(lst, k)
    return islice(subsets, num_subsets)
```

This saves you from sorting the whole list of length N. However, the backtracking search and the branch-and-bound algorithm don't benefit much from this since they both already use bounds on the sum to eliminate branches early; neither would need to iterate to the end of a long list when T is small.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it involves dynamic programming.

First, imagine if we have a data structure that looks like this:

```
for each count of elements to use
    for each possible sum
        for each starting index
            count of ways to get there (with or without that starting index)
```

It isn't too hard to write code to fill this in.  For `[6,8,3,9]` you would get something like this:

```
counts_by_count_by_sum_by_index = [
    { # empty sets
        0: [1, 1, 1, 1]
    },
    { # 1 element sets
        3: [1, 1, 1, 0],
        6: [1, 0, 0, 0],
        8: [1, 1, 0, 0],
        9: [1, 1, 1, 1],
    },
    { # 2 element sets
        9: [1, 0, 0, 0],
       11: [1, 1, 0, 0],
       12: [1, 1, 1, 0],
       14: [1, 0, 0, 0],
       15: [1, 0, 0, 0],
       17: [1, 1, 0, 0],
    },
    { # 3 element sets
       17: [1, 0, 0, 0],
       18: [1, 0, 0, 0],
       20: [1, 1, 0, 0],
       23: [1, 0, 0, 0],
    },
    { # 4 element sets
       26: [1, 0, 0, 0]
    }
]
```

If you had more elements, this data structure can get big but scales in a pseudo-polynomial way.  Specifically `O((size of elements) * (size of set) ^ 3)`.

With this data structure, it is easy to write a search by sum, that then recursively finds the solutions in lexicographic (by indexes used) order.

If you want, it is also possible to find, say, what the millionth solution is without having to generate the previous ones.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but generating all possible sums in advance is equivalent to generating all (n choose k) combinations in the worst case, isn't it?

Comment: It is possible to write this algorithm with a "just in time" implementation of the data structure using priority queues.  That sounds fun.  But I would have to do a lot of thinking about how to make it work.

Comment: I must be missing something. This seems extremely inefficient. How would this work with a 1000 element array and you need to find the first one million subsets of length 100 with the smallest sum. For example, you have `for each possible sum` implying that all of the sums have been generated. Aren't we to avoid this? I am more than aware of the prowess of @btilly and I genuinely believe that I'm lacking something here.

Comment: @JosephWood I don't think `T=1000000` fits the **(T being small)** constraint.

Comment: @user3386109, I would say relative to `nCk(1000, 100) ~= 6.385051e+139`, it is fits the small constraint quite well.

Comment: @JosephWood Relative to a naive implementation, it is very efficient.  In absolute terms, a 4th degree polynomial is a challenge.  Hence my comment on a "just in time" implementation of the data structure.  If the data structure is set up so that you only generate what you need of it, then it would work for the first million solutions.

Comment: @kaya3 No.  If the arrays have (as in these examples) integers, then the number of possible things you can sum to is limited to `O((size of elements) * (size of set))`.  Which is much, much smaller than `n choose k`.

Comment: If the size of the elements can be exponential in *n* then the sums can all be distinct; e.g. for a list `[1, 2, 4, 8, ...]`. Then it's not smaller than (n choose k).

Comment: @kaya3 Hence my use of the word "pseudopolynomial".  The ideas of this solution are the ideas of the standard subset sum algorithm.  Which works very well in practice.

Comment: I understood that. But you said it is *"much, much smaller than n choose k"* and that relies on an assumption not present in the question. But you already answered my question by saying that you can build the data structure "just-in-time" with a priority queue instead of precomputing it.

Comment: @btilly, I'm trying very hard to see where you are coming from, however there is a lot of hand waving in your language with no real explanation of how these data structures are created. E.g. _"Imagine you have a data structure..."_ and _"If the data structure is set up so that you only generate what you need"_. How exactly do you do that efficiently? How do we generate this data structure "just in time", as you say, efficiently? I believe you have something of substance here, but I genuinely don't understand how this can be implemented efficiently.

Comment: @JosephWood In the priority queues comment I said, *But I would have to do a lot of thinking about how to make it work.*  What that means is that I have a good idea about how to do it, but the actual implementation is complex.  If you want to take a stab at it, you need to replace the `k-element sets` with a stream that returns pairs `(value, counts)`.  That stream should use generated values if they exist, and generate more if they don't.  The generate more should be to pick partial calculations off of priority queues.

Comment: If you are familiar with, say, how to iterate through Hamming numbers, the idea isn't too hard.  But it takes some work.